# How do remote filesystems (nfs ssfhs) handle remote-to-remote copies?

Tags: filesystems, nfs, remote, copy, sshfs

After working with a few large files over sshfs, one question started dwelling in my mind.

Suppose I have a [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) (or NFS for that matter) mount on `~/remodetir` and I want to do something like

```
cp ~/remotedir/foo ~/remotedir/some/weird/path/bar
```

Does sshfs (or NFS) handle it in a smart way or do they transfer the file back-and-forth just because the cp command is running in my local CPU?

Comment: Define "smart way"?

Comment: @JimB, like with SMB where the client can ask the server to perform a local copy using RPC.

Comment: I am almost 95% certain that SSHFS is pretty dumb, but I don't know much about the NFS internals.

Comment: @JimB yes, a good definition of "smart way" would be the one given Zoredache, above.

Comment: There was a discussion on whether it is possible to [copy remote files on nfs without round-trip](http://superuser.com/q/337778/128116) on superuser.com. The conclusion was that it is not possible in general, but tools exists to support this.

Comment: Yes, server-side copy is in the May 2012 draft of NFSv4.2.

Comment: Thanks, @DmitriChubarov I guess that the same would be valid for `sshfs` for similar reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sshfs` makes local `mv` calls for `mv`.

I assume this is similar for `cp`.

Not sure if this is the case if the remote `sshd` restricted to `internal-sftp`.

edit:

File flows through local machine for `cp` as well (confirmed with network traffic).

> $ sshfs -V
>   SSHFS version 2.4
>   FUSE library version: 2.8.6
>   fusermount version: 2.8.6
>   using FUSE kernel interface version 7.12

Comment: So the local call for `mv` really means data transferred from the server to the client and back? 

Because, AFAIK, `mv` only messes with file handlers, or hardlinks, if you prefer, so the size of the file moved by `mv` doesn't matter so much, as long as filesystem borders are not crossed.